# the data binding in sapui5 list gives no data

Tags: javascript, sapui5

My problem keeps appearing every time I want to display JSON data in a list of sapui5.

I received **no data** .

I'll add the Extended Syntax for Calculated Fields
`<data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax="complex">` but no result, 
so I have a JSON file with the nam invoices and XML view containing the list.

```js
<mvc:View xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns="sap.m" controllerName="tmp.Zprojetyoussra.controller.InvoiceList"
 xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<List
  headerText="invoiceListTitle"
  class="sapUiResponsiveMargin"
  width="auto"
  items="{invoice>/Invoices}">
  <items>
   <ObjectListItem
    title="{invoice>Quantity} x {invoice>ProductName}"/>
  </items>
 </List>
</mvc:View>
```

```html
{
  "Invoices": [
 {
   "ProductName": "Pineapple",
   "Quantity": 21,
   "ExtendedPrice": 87.2000,
   "ShipperName": "Fun Inc.",
   "ShippedDate": "2015-04-01T00:00:00",
   "Status": "A"
 },
 {
   "ProductName": "Milk",
   "Quantity": 4,
   "ExtendedPrice": 9.99999,
   "ShipperName": "ACME",
   "ShippedDate": "2015-02-18T00:00:00",
   "Status": "B"
 },
 {
   "ProductName": "Canned Beans",
   "Quantity": 3,
   "ExtendedPrice": 6.85000,
   "ShipperName": "ACME",
   "ShippedDate": "2015-03-02T00:00:00",
   "Status": "B"
 },
 {
   "ProductName": "Salad",
   "Quantity": 2,
   "ExtendedPrice": 8.8000,
   "ShipperName": "ACME",
   "ShippedDate": "2015-04-12T00:00:00",
   "Status": "C"
 },
 {
   "ProductName": "Bread",
   "Quantity": 1,
   "ExtendedPrice": 2.71212,
   "ShipperName": "Fun Inc.",
   "ShippedDate": "2015-01-27T00:00:00",
   "Status": "A"
 }
  ]
}
```

Comment: This is very less information to be able to understand the real problem. Could you share the model information also. i.e where do you create model, name the model etc. 

Manifest and controller files are needed.

Comment: Where did you initialize the model?

Comment: i ve bound it directly in the xml view should i initialize it ?

Comment: You must at least create it somewhere and add it under the name 'invoice'. Where is that happening? Give the list an id and try sap.ui.getCore().byId('my-list-id').getBindingInfo('items'); What does it say?

Comment: Did you say model name is "invoices"? you are using only "invoice" in your view.